# Unable to observe an array of objects in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an array of objects within a component like this:

```
checkboxes: [
    {
        label: 'A',
        state: false
    },
    {
        label: 'B',
        state: false
    },
    {
        label: 'C',
        state: false
    }
]
```

In my Handlebars template, I have a loop to show the list of checkboxes and each checkbox state maps back to the array item like this:

```
{{#each checkboxes as |item|}}
    <li><input type="checkbox" checked={{item.state}}> {{item.label}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

I wrote an observer to observe changes to the array but it doesn't seem to work:

```
observeCheckboxes: function() {
    console.log(this.get('checkboxes').toArray());
}.observes('checkboxes.[]')
```

How do I observe changes to the checkbox states so I can get a list of checked items?

Answer (score 0):

Change your observer to observe `checkboxes.@each.state`.

Have a look through the documentation [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/) for a complete overview.

If possible, try to avoid using an observer, and rather use a computed property, and then also to rather define computed properties and observers as Ember.computed & Ember.observer.

Here is a [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/9ec28e3a67e22e77bc3a7ba8a0a2850b?openFiles=components.checkbox-list.js%2Ctemplates.components.checkbox-list.hbs) that demonstrates why your observer is not firing.